# Is StreamingOutput in Jersey buffered?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have two questions regarding StreamingOutput in Jersey:

1) Is it already buffered by the jax-rs runtime? I have seen some examples that create BufferedWriter from the OutputStream object when overriding the write() method. But I wonder if that is really necessary.

2) Does Jersey or the jax-rs runtime for that matter close the OutputStream object after the stream is finished?

Thanks,

Geg

Answer (score 1):

For top efficiency, consider wrapping an OutputStreamWriter 
within a BufferedWriter so as to avoid frequent converter invocations. 
For example: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput;
StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException,
                        WebApplicationException {
                        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
                        writer.write(msg);
                        writer.flush();
                }
            };
```